# Redireccionar al link depues del login PHP

Tags: php, html5

Lo que necesito es que se me envíe a un apartado en específico después de iniciar sesión.

Ejemplo: Si yo escribo en mi URL http://localhost/tienda/empleado?id=1

1. Antes de que llegue a esa URL debo de iniciar sesión.
2. Una vez iniciada sesión, me debe redireccionar a la URL de ejemplo (http://localhost/tienda/empleado?id=1) y no a mi dashboard

No sé si me logré explicar.

Ese es mi código HTML para hacer el login:

```
<form class="mt-4" method="POST" action="validar">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-dark">Usuario</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text-dark">Contraseña</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

Este es mi código PHP para validar el acceso:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    require_once 'config/conex.config.php';

    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? trim($_POST['email']) : null;
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where email = :email");
    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
    $stmt->execute();

    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($user) {
        $isVerified = password_verify($password, $user['password']);
        if ($isVerified) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            //header("Location: dashboard");
            header("Location:" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
            exit();
        } else {
            $_SESSION['status_error'] = "Incorrect Credentials";
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['status_error'] = "Incorrect Credentials";
    }
} header("Location: login");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paso por aquí para comentarles sobre la solución de mi problema por si alguien le sirve.

1. Lo primero que hice, fue que en mi página de destino establecí una variable donde almacenara la URL Destino.

```html
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['pagina_actual'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // i.e. "about.php"
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    $_SESSION['pagina_actual'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // i.e. "about.php"
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

1. Después en mi validación PHP, recupero esa variable donde me llevara a la URL destino.

```html
header("Location: ". $_SESSION['pagina_actual']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opcion puede ser, capturar la URL en la pagina destino y devolverla como un parametro para tu login, por ejemplo, el usuario entra en su browser:

https://tuweb.com/tienda/empleado?id=1

En la pagina destino tienes una condicion que revisa la sesion iniciada (PHP antes del HTML)

```php
<?php

session_start();

# Si no existe la sesion iniciada redirige
if (!isset($_SESSION["user"])){
  $url = filter_var($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
  $url = rawurlencode($url);
  header ("Location:" . "https://tuweb.com/login/?url=" . $url );  
  exit();
}
?>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Pagina destino</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h1>Alguna pagina</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Con lo anterior aseguras hacer el redirect si no hay sesion abierta para el usuario, luego en la pagina de login capturas el parametro que estas pasando como "url"

```php
<?php
  # Si no hay ningun parametro URL, que el redirect sea al panel
  $redirect = isset($_GET["url"])?$_GET["url"]:"/panel";
  $redirect = rawurldecode($redirect);
  
  # Tu script que procesa tu login
  ...
  if ($isVerified) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        header("Location:" . $redirect);
        exit();
    }
  ...
  
?>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Tu pagina de login</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h1>Tu formulario de login</h1>
     ....
  </body>
</html>
```